# Copy large datasets from Hive to local directory

Tags: hadoop, hive

Im trying to copy data from a hive table to my local dir.
The code that I am using is:

```
nohup hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true; set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false; select * from sample_table;" | sed 's/[\t]/|/g'  > /home/sample.txt &
```

The issue is the file will be around 400 GB and the process takes forever to complete.

Is there any better way to do it, like compressing the file as it is being generated.

I need to have the data as .txt file but im not able to get a quick work around for this problem.

Any smart ideas would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing it with the `-getmerge` option of the `hadoop` command? That'd typically what I use to merge Hive text tables and export to a local share drive.

```
hadoop fs -getmerge ${SOURCE_DIR}/table_name ${DEST_DIR}/table_name.txt
```

I think the `sed` command would also be slowing things down significantly. If you do the character replacement in Hive prior to extracting the data, that would be faster than a single-threaded `sed` command running on your edge node.

Comment: When I do getmerge, i am not getting the column names. Since my original data is in RCFile format, there seems some issue while the conversion happens

Comment: If `getmerge` performs better for you, then you can add the headers after the fact: `echo $'header1,header2,header3' | cat - original_file.txt > file_with_header.txt`